# How can I set the array key returned by Laravel's query builder?

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I have two tables, `page` and `edit`.

`page`

```
+----+-----------+
| id | page_name |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | page      |
+----+-----------+
```

`edit`

```
+----+---------+------+
| id | page_id | name |
+----+---------+------+
|  1 |       1 | home |
|  1 |       1 | side |
+----+---------+------+
```

Right now I have a relationship defined linking the two together. It returns something like this:

```
array(
  'id' => 1,
  'page_name' => 'page',
  'edit' => array(
    0 => array(
      'id' => 1,
      'page_id' => 1,
      'name' => 'home'
    ),
    1 => array(
      'id' => 2,
      'page_id' => 1,
      'name' => 'side'      
    )
  )
)
```

I would like to be able to set the key of the `edit` array to the value of a certain column. Like so:

```
array(
  'id' => 1,
  'page_name' => 'page',
  'edit' => array(
    'home' => array( // the key is the name column
      'id' => 1,
      'page_id' => 1,
      'name' => 'home'
    ),
    'side' => array( // the key is the name column
      'id' => 2,
      'page_id' => 1,
      'name' => 'side'      
    )
  )
)
```

How can I do this using Laravel's query builder? Or is this something I'll have to format & structure manually with a loop?

Comment: You have to manually build this after the query returns the data.

Comment: Too bad, but I do understand, as it can get complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution

```
//the page you will work with
$page = Page::find(1);

//his edits, by pairs array('name' => 'id', ..)
$page_edit_lists = $page->edit()->list('id', 'name');    

//now, look for a name
$edit_name = 'grammar fix';
$edit_id = array_get($page_edit_lists , $edit_name); //if exist or null

//now get the row by is ID
$page_edits = $page->edit()->get();
//when edits data is already loaded, so it will loop for you..
$edit = $page_edits->find($edit_id);
//or by dynamic querying, SELECT .. WHERE id = ? ..
$edit = $page->edit()->find($edit_id);
```

Didn't test it, but i think you get the idea.
And sory for my poor english..

Comment: Thanks. That's close to what I did; not exactly, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections
keyBy().

> $collection = collect([
>       ['product_id' => 'prod-100', 'name' => 'desk'],
>       ['product_id' => 'prod-200', 'name' => 'chair'], ]);
>
> $keyed = $collection->keyBy('product_id');
>
> $keyed->all();
>
> /*
>       [
>           'prod-100' => ['product_id' => 'prod-100', 'name' => 'Desk'],
>           'prod-200' => ['product_id' => 'prod-200', 'name' => 'Chair'],
>       ]
>   */